# Is there a way I can convert string to integer and add integer

Tags: python

```
myAge = input()
print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + 1 'in a year')
```

This code always returns:

> invalid line base 10.

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are parsing a string as integer by using `int()`, make sure that the string contains a valid number and no invalid characters. For example, if you give `23a` as input, the invalid `a` character will cause the error that it is not a valid literal for int base 10.

The code works fine for me, apart from the small typo you have in the code just before the string `'in a year'` (there should not be `1`). And also, `myage` and `myAge` are different.

```
>>> myAge = input()
>>> print('you  will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year')
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to read an input from user and add a number and then print it:

```py
myAge = input()
print("you will be " + str(int(myAge) + 1) + " in a year")
```

or

```py
myAge = input()
myAge = int(myAge) + 1
print("you will be " + str(myAge) + " in a year"
```

(It's python3 syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```
myAge=input("Enter your Age: ") #asks for input

myAge = int(myAge)+1 #converts myAge into an integer and adds one

print("You will be "+str(myAge)+" in a Year") #converts back myAge into a str and prints it
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter your Age: 79
You will be 80 in a Year
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I found when running the program I did not input number in input function. Thanks you all

Comment: You are welcome. Wish you a good programming session

Answer (score 0):

You have a stary '1' after the cast to str. Try the following:

```
myAge = input()
print('you  will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year')
```